# Unique identity issue on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When saving to Firebase with the push method, unique id is occurring.

How do I make it not happen?

(I have little English language. It is very good if you tell it simple.)

Comment: Saving to Firebase with Push **will** generate a unique ID. You should have read the documentation first

Answer (score 3):

Just use `setValue()` method directly on the reference like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child("Users").child("name").setValue("John");
```

But I recommend you reading [Firebase official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/).